# What is the difference between Excel and CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, google-sheets

I am learning about Python. Now I am trying to store the data to **.csv** file using **pandas** library.

I know csv is **comma separated values**, the data is separated by **comma(,)**.  My doubt is since both excel and csv files store data in a sheet, what is the difference between them?

Comment: "Excel" is a software from Microsoft and "csv" is is a text file that uses a delimiter to separate values in rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major differences between Excel XLSX and CSV file format are the file size and the formatting.

In a *.CSV file, the file size is smaller, and the data looks like this:
(there is no formatting, just raw data)
[image]

And if you open using a text editor, you'd get this:

```
idx,col1,col2
123,aaa,xxx
456,bbb,yyy
789,ccc,zzz
```

And in a *.XLSX file, the file size is larger, and the data looks like this:
(this format allows formatting such as tables, borders, background color, bold, etc)
[image]

And if you open with a text editor, you'd get this:

```
PK     ! A7傁n     [Content_Types].xml ?(?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 琓蒼?絎?D綱墶嚜??[$?榵扻$跺(鼄'fQU??Ql蟍&?&YB@鉲.鶼O$`璻?鼿烢偆琕嵆悑5?
镲拥 L岗b.j""%5?3缌騈锽珗?C%?妾?陕YK)ub8x僐-J轜技Q23V$瘺sU.旝?盤勾?I晔?燷県:C@i?╩23???g€/#莺矢2
泌x|`隚簼惝秛_?傃悓U燨詹w筳鋸髾s箪4去瓑-蔤e霳?e|鮫,ん佅??愸y絼s?i? 藓??s??耵V7?麛幵88彍? 梬a懏:??霤rh伥??轁鄸??   PK     ! 礥0#?   L   _rels/.rels ?(?     
<truncated>
```

Generally, I use CSV format to **store** raw data, and use XLSX format to **present** the data.

Comment: When using MS Excel to load both CSV and XLSX files, the data is *presented* in sheets!

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is both excel and csv file stores data in sheet.

They do not both store data in a sheet. There is no sheet in a csv file.

This is a common misunderstanding because windows uses Excel to open csv files when you double click. Excel puts the text from the csv file into a sheet, but that sheet is created by Excel, it doesn't exist in the csv file, even when you save it.

Here are some ways you can see the difference:

If you try to add a second sheet and save as csv, it will say not supported.

If you right-click > edit the csv file instead of double-click, it will open in notepad.

If you give the sheet a name like "Test", then save and close the file, then open it again, the sheet name will not be saved. Excel will use the filename as the sheet name.

If you close the file, and rename it to something like "Test.csv", then open the file in Excel, the sheet name will now say "Test".